# MySQL multi-word search with one query

Tags: mysql, search, text, sql-like

I'm wanting to do an ANDing or ORing in my MySQL query, but the LIMIT needs to be the same regardless.

eg. `SELECTION * FROM table WHERE text LIKE %word1 OR word2 OR word3% LIMIT 10`

I'd like this to work the same way it does on Twitter.

Comment: In case it isnt just a typo in your question, then replace SELECTION with SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (text LIKE %word1%) OR (text LIKE %word2%) 
OR (text LIKE %word3%) LIMIT 10
```